# unpleasant comment

Tags: discussion, best-practice

I got into a difficult situation where I can't use my primary laptop. I posted a question on Ask Ubuntu seeking for help and the first comment I received feels arrogant. is it OK? IMHO it doesn't sound welcoming and I think it goes against SO [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

is it just me too sensitive? do you find this comment rude?

The comment: [Can't open Files, Terminal, and Screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165010/cant-open-files-terminal-and-screenshot#comment1942135_1165010)

> Why don't you uninstall it and see if the damage is permanent before seeking a solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the comment is a little bit brusque, and a little bit rude in the wording, but not enough to really warrant any CoC violation action beyond the comment deletion.

As such, comment deleted, but also consider that your response to the comment about the comment being 'arrogant' is just as unhelpful and problematic as it tends to do nothing but incite a fight, so it was removed as well.

Next time you feel a comment is abusive towards you just use a mod flag and ask us to evaluate it.  Don't rebuke a comment with an accusatory comment.